# Mysqld.pid No Of Processes Are Not The Same As Threshold

Tags: mysql, database-administration, mysql-error-1064

I get the below issue every Sunday even the event scheduler is turned off and I haven't any event created for any database and this happens in different times (yesterday happened at 18:30 and the last week happened at 15:22)

mysqld.pid No of processes are not the same as threshold Running Processes = 0 threshold=1

So what can I do ?

Comment: look for cron jobs and see what they do.

Comment: I did it but I didn't catch anything related to the issue and I edited the post now because it happened in different times every Sunday

Comment: Include the mysql error log covering before and immediately after these times.